# Oracle Sql Developer 3.1 Unable to see Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I am using Oracle SQL Developer 3.1.06 and connected to 11g EE. Whenever I will click edit in any procedure in the left pane, showing "create or replace" in the right side window.. I am not able to see any procedure code. I am able to see the procedure in same login in toad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the user you are logging in with is the owner of the objects?

You can check the owner by looking into the ALL_OBJECTS table:

```
    SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%MYOBJECT%'
```

The user you are logging into could perhaps only have limited view rights preventing you from accessing the code. If you found the owner, you could browse in the connection window to other users and select the procedure from the relevant user. You should then be able to see everything.

Answer (score 0):

I have a user called LOW_PRIVS.

They only have RESOURCE and CONNECT.

I create a procedure.

I open procedure.

[image]

Here is what we run to get the source code on a local procedure:

```
WITH src AS (
    SELECT ROWNUM,
           line,
           text,
           origin_con_id
      FROM sys.all_source
     WHERE type    = :type
       AND owner   = :owner
       AND name    = :name
)
SELECT text
  FROM src,
       (
           SELECT MAX(origin_con_id) max_orig
             FROM src
       )
 WHERE origin_con_id   = max_orig
 ORDER BY line
```

We're hitting the ALL_SOURCE view that belongs to SYS. That should work for anyone.

But test and verify.

Note: I am on version 18.2 - that is many years newer than version 3.1. For best support, upgrade.